# Why does internet seem so slow on ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, internet

I recently switched Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10 and I have been experiencing very slow wifi internet connection ever since. Speedtest shows me that my download speed is a 1/4 of what it used to on Windows.

I tried changing my mtu from 1500 to 1492 but it didn't solve it.

I'm using a wireless usb adapter.

output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1038:0617 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Apex M750 TKL
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c08c Logitech, Inc. G PRO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: A lot more information is needed. How you are connected to internet?

Comment: I am connected via wifi

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: I don't get any output after running that command

Comment: Are you using a USB adapter?

Comment: Yes, I am using a USB adapter

Comment: Post output of `lsusb` then.

Comment: Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1038:0617 SteelSeries ApS SteelSeries Apex M750 TKL
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1532:0504 Razer USA, Ltd Razer Kraken 7.1 Chroma
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c08c Logitech, Inc. G PRO Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: What speeds are you actually seeing?

Comment: download: 2.53 Mbps, it used to be 10 Mbps when I used windows

Comment: Do you know the difference between megabits and megabytes? :-)